# How to replace the image in ImageView by another one picked by user form gallery?

Tags: java, android

I want the my app to change the profile pic as selected by the user from gallery when he touches the ImageView(placeholder). My current code opens the gallery but as soon as you select a pic the app stops working. Also, It is in the navigation bar. So, it would be great if any of you out there can help.

Here's my MainActivity.java (You may ignore the part not needed)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
private ImageView chooseImage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ImageView startEmergency = (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.start_emergency));

    startEmergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent emergencyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmergencyActActivity.class);

            startActivity(emergencyIntent);
        }
    });

    TextView myHealth = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.myHealth));

    myHealth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent healthIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HealthActivity.class);

            startActivity(healthIntent);
        }
    });

   /* TextView browse=(TextView) (findViewById(R.id.browse));

    browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent browseIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, BrowseActivity.class);

            startActivity(browseIntent);
        }
    });*/

    TextView myAccount = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.myAccount));

    myAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent accountIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(accountIntent);
        }
    });

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });

}
private void openGallery() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            EditText edit = ((EditText) v);
            Rect outR = new Rect();
            edit.getGlobalVisibleRect(outR);
            Boolean isKeyboardOpen = !outR.contains((int)ev.getRawX(), (int)ev.getRawY());
            System.out.print("Is Keyboard? " + isKeyboardOpen);
            if (isKeyboardOpen) {
                System.out.print("Entro al IF");
                edit.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edit.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

            edit.setCursorVisible(!isKeyboardOpen);

        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    if (searchMenuItem == null) {
        return true;
    }

    searchItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to create an Intent.
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=hospitals");

            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

            startActivity(mapIntent);

            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}}
```

And the navigation_header.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:text="Name"
        android:background="@null"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.admin.thehealthapp, PID: 5301
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/37329 }} to activity {com.example.admin.thehealthapp/com.example.admin.thehealthapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/37329 from pid=5301, uid=10081 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3813)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/37329 from pid=5301, uid=10081 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:524)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:438)
                  at com.example.admin.thehealthapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:117)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6498)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3809)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3856) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Try to figure out reason of crash from logs.

Comment: It should be `requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO`. You should check if the request code is the same as the one you've passed to the `startActivityForResult(....)` method.

Comment: What is your error printed in your log console ?

Comment: As the error specifies, your app doesn't have the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, you need to add that to your manifest or ask that permission from the user at runtime.

Comment: I've added the log.

Comment: It seems you failed to ask for runtime permissions on Android 6.0+

Comment: Ok Thanks, that worked for me